# Error converting matlab code to python

Tags: python, matlab

I want to convert this code from matlab to python, but it does not generate the list correctly.

This is the code in Matlab:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.7142:(size(Z,2)-1)*0.7142, 0:0.7142:(size(Z,1)-1)*0.7142);
```

This is the code I wrote in Python:

```
a = np.mgrid[0:0.7142:(len(A)-1)*0.7142]
b = np.mgrid[0:0.7142:(len(A)-1)*0.7142]
x, y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
```

This returns a list with only one element, which is 0. The size of list A here is 1292352. 
Why is this happening/ how can I fix it?

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar of your question, but I do not know if I got it 100% correct, but if so, your problem is RAM. If A is 1292352 elements long, meshgrid will return an array that is 1292352 rows by 1292352  columns. Assuming a standard float for each element, this is 106.891 TB worth of data (uncompressed). I am pretty sure you do not have that much RAM

Answer (score 0):

In Python,the step of the slice is the last number:

```
a = np.mgrid[0:(len(A)-1)*0.7142:0.7142]
b = np.mgrid[0:(len(A)-1)*0.7142:0.7142]
x, y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
```

You could do it without a slice and it also looks like you don't need `b` since it is the same as `a`:

```
a = np.arange(len(A)-1)*0.7142
x, y = np.meshgrid(a, a)
```

That being said, your list A is too big and you will run out of memory when trying to do this.